# Take a specific document for a mail in VBA on MAC

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am on MAC so even if I know VBA i dont know how to translate it on MAC. I have this code but I have a problem about the path

I want a macro who join a specific document (already existing) in this path :

```
Path = "Z:\Reporting\" & ext3 & "\" & ext & " - " & ext2 & ".pdf"
```

(with ext1/2/3 are cells value)
and sending it by mail with Outlook MAC.

This is my code :

```
Sub SaveMailRangeAsPDFIn2016()
    Dim FilePathName As String
    Dim strbody As String

        FilePathName = ?


'Create the body text in the strbody string
    strbody = "<FONT size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">"
    strbody = strbody & "Hi there" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
        "This is line 1" & "<br>" & _
        "This is line 2" & "<br>" & _
        "This is line 3" & "<br>" & _
        "This is line 4"
    strbody = strbody & "</FONT>"


MacExcel2016WithMacOutlookPDF _
    subject:="test", _
    mailbody:=strbody, _
    toaddress:="xxxxx@xxxx.xx", _
    ccaddress:="", _
    bccaddress:="", _
    displaymail:="yes", _
    accounttype:="", _
    accountname:="", _
    attachment:=FilePathName

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

with the fonction :

```
Function MacExcel2016WithMacOutlookPDF(subject As String, mailbody As String, _
    toaddress As String, ccaddress As String, _
    bccaddress As String, displaymail As String, _
    accounttype As String, accountname As String, _
    attachment As String)
    Dim ScriptStr As String, RunMyScript As String

    ScriptStr = subject & ";" & mailbody & ";" & toaddress & ";" & ccaddress & ";" & _
                bccaddress & ";" & displaymail & ";" & accounttype & ";" & _
                accountname & ";" & attachment

    'Call the RDBMacOutlook.scpt script file with the AppleScriptTask function
    RunMyScript = AppleScriptTask("RDBMacOutlook.scpt", "CreateMailInOutlook", CStr(ScriptStr))


End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOS/OSX uses a different path separator than Windows `"\"`.

So if you have your path hard coded in VBA like this

```
Path = "Z:\Reporting\" & ext3 & "\" & ext & " - " & ext2 & ".pdf"
```

you can check the operating system and use

```
If Application.OperatingSystem Like "*Mac*" Then
    Path = "your mac path"
Else
    Path = "Z:\Reporting\" & ext3 & "\" & ext & " - " & ext2 & ".pdf"
End If
```

Note that `Application.PathSeparator` returns the actual path separator used by the operating system.